# Angular 2 Modal Service insert dynamic (unknown) component

Tags: angular, render

I am trying to  dynamically insert a component into custom modal window component

my modal component receives a URL to a html file with a component inside:

```
<a modal bodyUrl="/some/path/body.html">
```

body.html:

```
  <hello-component></hello-component>
```

I am loading body.html's content into the modal's DOM via http and inserting it into the template via htmlBinding attribute.

However, my component won't render. Is there a way to force to re-rendering? Or something like that?

Thank you for your help!

Update 1:

Both answers below gave me an idea to pass a component type as an Input of a modal and use DynamicComponentLoader to bootstrap a component

Here is plunk with concept:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kbD8wVgTr0b0J4rvk4uY?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `DynamicComponentLoader` instead of the `innerHTML` property. In this case, the component will be compiled and added into the template.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 'Parent (<child id="child"></child>)'
})
class MyApp {
  constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, injector: Injector) {
    dcl.loadAsRoot(ChildComponent, '#child', injector);
  }
}
```

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Thank for the answer!  The problem is what I cannot know the type of the component I am passing to the modal window.  Is it possible to dynamically load a component by it's name as string? What would happen if my body's content would have multiple components inside?

Comment: I just figured out  what you could pass a type of component as input. Thank you for inspiration!:)